# accessing the next tr from an input in the row above using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Is there any way to access a tr from an input of a tr above without adding row specific id's or classes?

```
<table>
<tr><td>just another row</td>
<tr><td><input name="inputToSerachFrom" type="text" /></td><tr>
<tr><td>I want to acces this row without adding id's or classes</td><tr>
<tr><td>just another row</td>
</table>

var rowINeed = $("input[name=inputToSerachFrom]").closest("tr").parent().noIdea();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the next `tr` from the input, without using any IDs, you can use this:

```
var nextRow = $(this).parents('tr').next();
```

Comment: This is indeed the way to go. 
Jan

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name=inputToSerachFrom]").closest("tr").next('tr:first')
```